# Facebook requesting permission

Tags: android, permissions, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing android application that integrates with facebook

what I want to do is to display this screen[image]

each time the user logged into facebook

how can this be done?

Comment: Why do you want to display it every time? The user only needs to authorize your application once.

Comment: ah ok .. so it is not possible :)

Comment: what do we mean by "EXPIRES" in the code?
like this fb.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));

Comment: you can revoke the permission for a user at the end of their session, with a button, or us javascript for an on exit execution of the script.  This would cause the user to have to reinstall or re-auth the app on each visit.  this is not recommended but can be done.

Comment: It can be done, just call to logout() method from the main Facebook.java file every time the user exits the app (You can check some Activity onDestroy() by example) and that will erase your session. For elegance and user experience you must to check before that that the session really exists and is valid with the isSessionValid() method. After that, your app will request Facebook login every time the user returns.

Comment: I think It's just not happened again if tap on allow button, can you post code here what you have done in code ?